# HTML5 banner for google spec and adform spec

Tags: html, banner-ads, double-click-advertising, google-advertising-id

Google's html5 banner specification is different to adform's.

adform's:
http://creative.adform.com/support/documentation/build-html5-banners/html5-banner-specifications/adding-clicktag-variables/

google's:
https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2672517?hl=en&ref_topic=2672541

Basically the way the URL works and the javascript files they say to include differs.

is it possible to create a banner - specifically the clickTAG / url function, that works for both networks?

Answer (score 0):

Adform is Google adwords third party vendor. Google adwords can not directly embed your banner 
Here is the vendor list :
https://support.google.com/3pascertification/table/4572577